# How to get back to the form page(with user entered form data) after successful login with angular?

Tags: angular

I have form, where user can fill the data and on submit the form, it should check if the user is authenticated, if he is not, he should then be redirected to the login page and after successful login,he should again be taken back to the form page with all his form data preserved. Is that possible with angular 4+? Any suggestions or idea would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is possible. You have to preseve your form data in a **service** or in the browser storage(**session storage** can be used for this).

in your form component.

```
public ngOninit(): void {
  const formValue = this.dataService.getFormValue();
  if(formValue) {
    this.form.patchValue(formValue) // or you can use setValue
  }
}

public onSubmit(): void {
   if(this.form.invalid) {
      return;
   }
   this.dataService.setFormValue(this.form.value);
}
```

In your service

```
private fromValue: any;

public setFormValue(value): void {
   this.formValue = value;
}

public getFormValue(): any {
  return this.formValue;
}
```

add your service to module.

Comment: How in a service?

Comment: Please explain me in detail.

Comment: wouldn't the data on the service be lost, when the service is called  again? (routing back from url/login to url/formpage)

Comment: No that wont happen. You have to provide the service in a upper level module. May be in the root module. It's in the angular official [doc](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)